# How to set timer for showing result time to JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jtextfield, sleep

I click on a JButton and I should get the final output below, in a JTextField:

```
01234567
```

I want to set a Timer so the result show out slowly for each number.

For example (In the JTextField), the result I wish should do that:
0 (1 sec later)
01 (1 sec later)
012 (1 sec later)
0123 ..........  01234567
(Output in JTextField is 01234567)

I'm currently using Thread.sleep but I don't get the result I want.
I first click on the JButton:
(1 sec later)
01234567

I'm currently using the code

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            textfield.setText("");

            for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
            {
                textfield.setText(i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to use Timer without changing "button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()......" ?? (I wish to not use Thread.sleep if I use Timer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Swing Timer and the Timer's actionPerformed method will repeatedly be called, and this will be your "loop". So get rid of the for loop inside the method and definitely get rid of the `Thread.sleep(...)`

```
ActionListener timerListener = new ActionListener(){
    private String text = "";
    private int count = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        text += // something based on count
        count++;
        textField.setText(text);
        // code to stop timer once count has reached max
    }
});
```

For example,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Tester extends JPanel {
   public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
   public static final String TEST_TEXT = "01234567";
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton button = new JButton(new ButtonAction());
   private Timer timer;

   public Tester() {
      add(textField);
      add(button);
   }

   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {

      public ButtonAction() {
         super("Press Me");
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_P);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
            return;
         }
         textField.setText("");
         timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
         timer.start();
      }
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      private String text = "";
      private int counter = 0;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         text += TEST_TEXT.charAt(counter);
         textField.setText(text);
         counter++;
         if (counter >= TEST_TEXT.length()) {
            timer.stop();
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Tester mainPanel = new Tester();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tester");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put `textfield.setText(textfield.getText()+i)` because if you don't do that you overwrite the actual content